# Creating custom RGB colours & implementing custom drawing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, drawrect

I'm trying to do custom drawing & I've created a custom colour:

```
fawYellowColour = [UIColor colorWithRed: (255.0/255.0 ) green: (221.0/255.0) blue: (0.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
```

I now want to use my custom colour to draw, I expected I could simply replace the preset colour with my custom `fawYellowColour` like this:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor fawYellowColour].CGColor);
```

However I get the message -

error: request for member 'CGColor' in something not a structure or union

Any ideas? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a variable called `fawYellowColour`. Then you try and send the message `-fawYellowColour` to `UIColor`, expecting a valid result. You should be getting a warning saying that this method doesn't exist. What you really want to say is

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, fawYellowColour.CGColor);
```